# Vertical CSS Timeline layout issue

Tags: html, css

I am creating a vertical CSS timeline.  I float elements left and right so that they stack with each column. This mostly works but I have noticed after a few elements a large gap appears

Look at the following [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVYPGY). After the 5th element a large gap appears on the left hand side which is not consistent with previous gaps, and again after a few more elements.  What is causing this?

Note that the produced HTML was produced from Angular

```
<ul class="timeline ng-scope">
    <li class="year first">July 2015</li>
    <li class="event highlightedSection ng-scope" ng-repeat="activity in activities">
        <span class="itemPoint"></span>

        <span class="time ng-binding">2 minutes</span>
        <div ng-if="activity.ContentType != 1" class="message ng-binding ng-scope">Device connected</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it looks like semantics in how it is made to 'best fit' on the timeline, there's just alot of content there and its taking up space. Note it happens when there is a picture.

Answer (score 0):

The basic cause is the way `float` works: it won't float an item to a position higher than the previous element! [See an example.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGPeeL)

This is *good*, because it means that when you float an image next to a paragraph, for example, it won't just float all the way up to the top of the page but stay next to the paragraph, which is where you want it! And in the case of your timeline, it means that all the list elements actually appear in order, going down the page - otherwise one tall item would cause smaller, later items to appear earlier in the timeline - which would be a bit counter-intuitive.

What you could potentially do, to make the timeline look nicer, is to use either javascript or your item-generation code to figure out whether the left or the right column is shorter, and dynamically add each item to the current shortest column rather than simply alternating left and right.